# New Col "YES" or "NO" based on success of match in R

Tags: r, binary

I'm just trying to create a new column that says "YES" or "NO" based on data in x that matches data in y.

```
x <- c("xx22","xx33","xx44", "xx55")
y <- c("xx22","ww66","xx55")
x <- data.frame(x)
y <- data.frame(y)
```

This is the output I'm hoping to get. My actual data set is of course much larger.

```
> x
     x match
1 xx22   YES
2 xx33    NO
3 xx44    NO
4 xx55   YES
```

This is the (partial) solution i have got so far.

```
x <- c("xx22","xx33","xx44", "xx55")
y <- c("YES", "YES", "YES")
x <- data.frame(x)
y <- data.frame(y)
y$match <- c("xx22","ww66","xx55")

> x$YN <- merge(x, y, all.x=TRUE, by ="x")
> x
     x YN.x YN.y
1 xx22 xx22  YES
2 xx33 xx33 <NA>
3 xx44 xx44 <NA>
4 xx55 xx55  YES
```

Comment: `x %>% mutate(Match = x %in% y$y)`

Comment: How do I get a "YES" or "NO" Value instead of TRUE and FALSE?

Comment: x Match
1 xx22  TRUE
2 xx33 FALSE
3 xx44 FALSE
4 xx55  TRUE

Comment: `x %>% mutate(Match = ifelse(x %in% y$y, "Yes", "No"))`

Comment: Works Perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dyplr::mutate` with an `ifelse` statement:

```
x <- c("xx22","xx33","xx44", "xx55")
y <- c("xx22","ww66","xx55")
x <- data.frame(x)
y <- data.frame(y)

x %>% mutate(Match = ifelse(x %in% y$y, "Yes", "No"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse` is vectorized. Hence in `base-R` option could be:

```
x$match <- ifelse(x$x %in% y$y, "Yes", "No")
x
#      x match
# 1 xx22   Yes
# 2 xx33    No
# 3 xx44    No
# 4 xx55   Yes
```

**Note:** There is no need to convert `y` as `data.frame`. `y` can be used as just a vector in expression as:

```
y <- c("xx22","ww66","xx55")
x$match <- ifelse(x$x %in% y, "Yes", "No")
```

**Data**

```
x <- c("xx22","xx33","xx44", "xx55")
y <- c("xx22","ww66","xx55")
x <- data.frame(x)
y <- data.frame(y)
```